# Using "RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding" with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I tried to use "RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding" for encryption. It is not supported in JCE. So I downloaded Bouncy Castle but it seems that Bouncy Castle also does not support this transformation. The following codes:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
```

throws

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    ....
Caused by: javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Unsupported padding PKCS7Padding
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.engineSetPadding(P11RSACipher.java:129)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform.setModePadding(Cipher.java:360)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:517)
    ... 4 more
```

Am I doing it correctly?

TIA.

Comment: Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"); works with bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar

Comment: You could use the algorithms in spec http://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html

Comment: PKCS1 specifies padding for RSA. PKCS5/7 specifies a padding for blockciphers, which RSA is not.

Comment: The requirements given is that RSA should be used and to specify "PKCS7 with Padding". There wasn't any mention of the mode (ECB, etc). Can I just put NONE for mode?

Comment: `None` is the proper mode. Concerning PKCS1 vs PKCS7 contact whoever gave you that requirement. It's very likely that they meant PKCS1.

Comment: I also want to note that PKCS#1v1.5 padding (often called PKCS1 padding) has been broken. OAEP padding (specified in PKCS#1v2.0) should be used instead.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Although `None` *is indeed the proper mode*, please note that the Sun/Oracle provider (in Java SE) doesn't understand `RSA/None`. Instead it uses `RSA/ECB` and then proceeds as if `RSA/None` is specified. Still, for maximum compatibility please use `RSA/ECB` (and `PKCS5Padding` instead of `PKCS7Padding` for block ciphers)

Answer (score 3):

Even if such a thing would exist, using RSA with PKCS#7 padding or a scheme directly derived from PKCS#7 padding would be insecure (or, to be more precise, it would not be CPA-secure).

What is infinitely more likely is that the client doesn't require PKCS#7 **padding** but that the encrypted data should be contained in a [**CMS message format**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652). PKCS#7 is a predecessor of this format, the PKCS#7 padding is only a small part of this specification.

Bouncy Castle contains an implementation of this format:

> Generators/Processors for S/MIME and CMS (PKCS7/RFC 3852).

currently contained in the `bcpkix*` JAR files.

Comment: Sorry, but I only have a basic understanding of encryption, and what you guys are talking about is just beyond me. My requirement is basically like this: we have a random one-time AES-256 key, and we need to encrypt this AES key using a recipient's public key (RSA-2048). The requirement given for the encryption of this AES key is "RSA-2048, PKCS7 with padding in enveloping mode". How do I do that?

Comment: Start by reading the CMS specification I linked to. Sorry, but this space is a bit short for a full explanation of CMS. Enveloping mode is certainly part of the CMS specification, so you don't just require PKCS#7 padding - as I already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to implement PKCS#7 padding as described in [RFC2315 section 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-10.3) note 2 for all RSA key sizes:

> Some content-encryption algorithms assume the
> input length is a multiple of k octets, where k > 1, and
> let the application define a method for handling inputs
> whose lengths are not a multiple of k octets. For such
> algorithms, the method shall be to pad the input at the
> trailing end with k - (l mod k) octets all having value k -
> (l mod k), where l is the length of the input. In other
> words, the input is padded at the trailing end with one of
> the following strings

and specifically:

> This padding method is well-defined if and only if k < 256; methods for larger k are an open issue for further study.

Which means that you *could* implement this for RSA with 2048-bit keys, but already 4096-bit keys are too much for arbitrary data. This is why PKCS7Padding is reserved for block ciphers where each block is usually between 128 and 256-bit. This is also why libraries don't generally support this sort of combination.

The above specification contains everything you need to know to implement the PKCS#7 padding scheme. When you do, you will pad your data using it and then encrypt with `RSA/ECB/NoPadding`. You might run into the problem that although the padded plaintext and the key size are the same, the encryption doesn't work. That's because your padded plaintext might still exceed the key. You may need to add a zero byte to the front of the plaintext and only pad (0x00 + plaintext) so that the most significant bits are unset.

Comment: Missing in above is the fact that PKCS#7 padding would not be cryptographically secure (besides of the operational problem with the size that you describe). Also see my answer for a more likely scenario why PKCS#7 would be required.

Comment: Sorry, but I only have a basic understanding of encryption, and what you guys are talking about is just beyond me. My requirement is basically like this: we have a random one-time AES-256 key, and we need to encrypt this AES key using a recipient's public key (RSA-2048). The requirement given for the encryption of this AES key is "RSA-2048, PKCS7 with padding in enveloping mode". How do I do that?

Comment: @user3573403 This is a strange request as you noticed from the answers. I'm not entirely sure if implementing PKCS#7 for RSA is such a good idea given the fact that my suggestion transforms it into something other than plain PKCS#7 padding (because of the leading zero byte). This requirement seems to be dictated by somebody to you. So, I guess this is an interoperability issue in which case you can implement it and see if it works. I won't provide code to do this, because I think this is a bad idea (as Maarten said, it is not CPA-secure).

Comment: @user3573403 There is still a chance that this is a misunderstanding and you mean RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in a hybrid encryption manner.

Answer (score 0):

To summaries my commenta, According to the java7 doc, There list of standard algorithms must be supported by every implementation of JCE [Cipher API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher). Bouncy castle support additional algorithms as well. I use  "`AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding`" in my application. You could find supported algorithms by bouncy castle in [algorithm section](http://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html)  and `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`  or `"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"` should work.

Comment: I want to use "RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding", not "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding". The bouncy castle jar that I downloaded is bcprov-ext-jdk15on-151.jar. Is "RSA/ECB/PKCS7Padding" supported?

Comment: @user3573403: PKCS7 padding with RSA doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Hi @GregS, why is PKCS7 padding with RSA not making sense? This was a requirement given to me.