# Encypting with php openssl and decrypting with Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, php-openssl

I am trying to encrypt a string with php open_ssl and then decrypt it with Java.  I thought I kind of understood what was going on, but apparently not.

At first I was unable to get the algorithms to match up.  From what I can gather, openssl_private_encrypt() is using RSA and although the documentation is about PKCS1_PADDING, from what I read it seems that it was changed to use PKCS5/7 to become more secure.  And I cannot get any Java cipher with RSA/NONE/PKCS5 or PKCS7.

But I thought I was having success by using NoPadding, and filling the block myself.  This is with an existing 512 bit key that I converted from DER to PEM with openssl.  I had a test string of

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

I was able to read in the private key in php and encrypt the text with

```php
$fp=fopen("/folder/private_key.pem","r");
$privkey_res=fread($fp,1024);
$privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privkey_res); 

$padding = OPENSSL_NO_PADDING;
openssl_private_encrypt($texttocrypt, $encryptedtext, $privkey, $padding);
file_put_contents("/folder/encrypted.txt", $encryptedtext );
```

Then back in Java I then was able to correctly decrypt that string using

```java
Cipher cipherb = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding");
cipherb.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
decrypted = cipherb.doFinal(text.getBytes());
```

So I thought I could get things working to be useful.  However, then I changed the test string slightly, like the last 'f' to 'g'

```
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdeg
```

And then I got complete garbage on the decryption.  Although no error.  And if I just changed the first character, it still decrypted correctly.

At this point I am not even sure what it is that I don't understand.  But is there a way to do my original goal?  Encrypt with php open_ssl and decrypt with Java.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use a padding? If you use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, then the plaintext must not be larger than modulus size minus 11 bytes. If you use OAEP with SHA-1, then the plaintext must not be larger than the modulus size minus 42 bytes.

Comment: What you have here is no encryption. It's called digital signature. The public key is used for encryption and the private key for decryption. If you do that the other way around, then you're signing something.

Comment: I can only guess what the issue here is, but I think it's the fact that you've changed the plaintext in a way that it is numerically larger than the modulus. In which case, you're encrypting *p mod n* and not *p*. Whether this is true depends on the actual value of the modulus.

Comment: To answer your comments, I would be more than pleased to use padding.  However, on the encryption side, the only padding available says it is PKCS1.  I tried to decrypt that with every padding variation that is available from bouncycastle, and they all got a padding exception.  I think  the encryption is using PKCS5/7, not PKCS1.  And there is no bouncycastle cipher to do that.

Comment: And you are right, it is a digital signature, but all the documentation is encryption/decryption so I tend use that terminology.  Your comment on the plaintext being larger than the modulus is also illuminating.  So I do need to go back to padding, but still cannot find a way to decrypt it.

Comment: In RSA plaintexts need to be strictly smaller than the modulus if expressed as numbers. If you need to encrypt larger values, then you should apply [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). You could limit your plaintexts to 512 bit and use an RSA key of 520 bit. One byte difference should be enough to prevent any accidental breaking of the plaintext, but then anything less than 2048 bit for RSA should not be used anymore. This is textbook RSA, which enables some very effective attacks. OAEP (PKCS#1 v2 padding) is considered secure today.

Comment: PKCS#5/PKCS#7 paddings are strictly block cipher paddings and [cannot (and should not) be used with RSA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28107880/1816580).

Comment: I just seem to be getting further and further afield from what I thought would (should?)  be fairly straightforward.  I started by creating a new 2048 bit key, and using openssl_private_encrypt.  I was then able to almost read that in Java, but got a BadPaddingException.  I can't determine exactly what padding scheme is being used on the encrypt by php/openssl.  What I did do is try every Cipher/Padding alternative I could find  but none of them work. Bouncycastle has a quite a few, but they all get various types of BadPaddingException.  So close....

Comment: Going back to basics - has anyone paired up php opensll with Java, and what exactly did you use?

Comment: The issue might be signature. Paddings for encrypting and signing are different. So, `openssl_private_encrypt` likely uses the signing padding, but `Cipher` tries to removed the encrypting padding. Java has a similar `Signature` class which is probably what you need to use.